# Tag-badge not awarded

Tags: support, status-bydesign

To get a bronze tag badge, one needs to achieve this:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

However, I [gave 20 non-wiki answers with a total score of 122](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15080/manu?tab=tags) on questions with the tag [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill). I gave my 20th answer some days ago, but still don't have a bronze badge for this tag. Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/164922)